# Split/slice vectors into sub-vectors and get their norms without a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, vectorization, norm

I have two vectors in MATLAB, `vectorA` and `vectorB` - both of equal lengths of 1280 elements. I want to split the vectors into sub-vectors of  length 256, giving 5 sub-vectors.

Once I have the slices, say `sliceA` and `sliceB`, I need to perform `norm` on the two slices.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
for i = 1:N
    sliceA = vectorA(i:round(i*1280/N);
    sliceB = vectorB(i:round(i*1280/N));
    distance = distance+norm(sliceA,sliceB);
end
distance = distance/N;
```

Is it possible to remove the loop using some insane MATLAB logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reshape` to make a 2D matrix of the slices

```
sliceA = reshape(vectorA, 256, 5);
sliceB = reshape(vectorB, 256, 5);
```

Then calculate the (Euclidean) norms and their sum for distance

```
norms = sqrt(sum((sliceA - sliceB).^2, 1));
distance = sum(norms)/5;
```

---

You can sum in either direction, depending which way you have reshaped the vector. Depending whether you want slices of 256 or 5, you may want to change the `DIM` argument of the `sum` to switch from summing down rows to summing across columns.

```
norms = sqrt(sum((sliceA - sliceB).^2, 1)); % Sums down rows, slices of 256
norms = sqrt(sum((sliceA - sliceB).^2, 2)); % Sums across cols, slices of 5
```

---

Note, you don't have to calculate both dimensions of the `reshape` function. As long as you choose a value which is a factor of the number of elements in your vector, you could do

```
sliceA = reshape(vectorA, 128, []); % correct number of slices of 128
sliceA = reshape(vectorA, [], N);   % This would use N how you are in the loop
```

Comment: You are a hero :) Thanks